# Nmap default scan technique

Tags: nmap

I'm a little bit confused about what is the default scan option for an nmap scan. For example:

```
nmap -A -p 22
```

Am I performing a SYN scan or TCP connect scan?

Answer (score 10):

When scanning TCP ports, Nmap will do a [SYN scan](https://nmap.org/book/man-port-scanning-techniques.html#idm46159113802432) by default and fall back to a [connect scan](https://nmap.org/book/man-port-scanning-techniques.html#idm46159113793664) if the user doesn't have sufficient privileges.

From [the docs](https://nmap.org/book/man-port-scanning-techniques.html):

> `-sS` (TCP SYN scan)
>
> SYN scan is the default and most popular scan option for good reasons. It can be performed quickly, scanning thousands of ports per second on a fast network not hampered by restrictive firewalls. [...]
>
> `-sT` (TCP connect scan)
>
> TCP connect scan is the default TCP scan type when SYN scan is not an option. This is the case when a user does not have raw packet
>   privileges. [...]

You can also use the verbose flag (`-v`) to find out which exact scan types are being run:

```
$ nmap -v -p 22 1.2.3.4

Starting Nmap 7.60 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2017-12-11 12:14 CET
Initiating Ping Scan at 12:14
Scanning 1.2.3.4 [2 ports]
Completed Ping Scan at 12:14, 0.00s elapsed (1 total hosts)
Initiating Parallel DNS resolution of 1 host. at 12:14
Completed Parallel DNS resolution of 1 host. at 12:14, 0.01s elapsed
Initiating Connect Scan at 12:14
Scanning xxx (1.2.3.4) [1 port]
Completed Connect Scan at 12:14, 0.00s elapsed (1 total ports)
Nmap scan report for xxx (1.2.3.4)
Host is up (0.000070s latency).

PORT   STATE  SERVICE
22/tcp closed ssh

Read data files from: /usr/bin/../share/nmap
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.04 seconds
```

```
$ sudo nmap -v -p 22 1.2.3.4

Starting Nmap 7.60 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2017-12-11 12:15 CET
Initiating Parallel DNS resolution of 1 host. at 12:15
Completed Parallel DNS resolution of 1 host. at 12:15, 0.01s elapsed
Initiating SYN Stealth Scan at 12:15
Scanning xxx (1.2.3.4) [1 port]
Completed SYN Stealth Scan at 12:15, 0.04s elapsed (1 total ports)
Nmap scan report for xxx (1.2.3.4)
Host is up (0.000045s latency).

PORT   STATE  SERVICE
22/tcp closed ssh

Read data files from: /usr/bin/../share/nmap
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.12 seconds
           Raw packets sent: 1 (44B) | Rcvd: 2 (84B)
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the priv. of the user executing the scan:

- for a privledged user, the default option is the -sS scan (TCP SYN scan)
- for an unpriledged user, the default option is the -sT scan (TCP connect() scan)